# compare and sort in VHDL

Tags: sorting, compare, vhdl

this is a code for sorting 4 element in VHDL:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity COMPARE_2 is
PORT(
clock   :in STD_LOGIC:='0';
En  :in STD_LOGIC:='0';
AA1 :buffer STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
AA2 :buffer STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
AA3 :buffer STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
AA4 :buffer STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);

Q1  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
Q2  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
Q3  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
Q4  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0)
);
end COMPARE_2;

architecture Behavioral of COMPARE_2 is
signal  A1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"09";
signal A2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"09";
signal A3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"09";
signal A4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"09";
begin
A1<=AA1;
A2<=AA2;
A3<=AA3;
A4<=AA4;
process(clock)
begin
if(clock'event and clock ='1') then
if( En='1') then    
    if (A1 >= A2 AND A1 >= A3 AND A1 >= A4) then    Q1 <=   A1; 
    elsif (A2 >= A3 AND A2 >= A4 AND A2 >= A1) then Q1 <=   A2;
    elsif( A3 >= A2 AND A3 >= A4 AND A3 >= A1) then Q1 <=   A3;
    elsif( A4 >= A3 AND A4 >= A2 AND A4 >= A1) then Q1 <=   A4;
    end if;

    if ((A1 <= A2 AND A1 >= A3 AND A1 >= A4 ) OR (A1 >= A2 AND A1 <= A3 AND A1 >= A4) OR (A1 >= A2 AND A1 >= A3 AND A1 <= A4) ) then    Q2 <=   A1; 
    elsif ((A2 <= A1 AND A2 >= A3 AND A2 >= A4 ) OR (A2 >= A1 AND A2 <= A3 AND A2 >= A4) OR (A2 >= A1 AND A2 >= A3 AND A2 <= A4)) then  Q2 <=   A2; 
    elsif ((A3 <= A1 AND A3 >= A2 AND A3 >= A4 ) OR (A3 >= A1 AND A3 <= A2 AND A3 >= A4) OR (A3 >= A1 AND A3 >= A2 AND A3 <= A4)) then  Q2 <=   A3; 
    elsif ((A4 <= A1 AND A4 >= A2 AND A4 >= A3 ) OR (A4 >= A1 AND A4 <= A2 AND A4 >= A3) OR (A4 >= A1 AND A4 >= A2 AND A4 <= A3)) then  Q2 <=   A4; 
    end if;

    if ((A1 <= A2 AND A1 <= A3 AND A1 >= A4 ) OR (A1 >= A2 AND A1 <= A3 AND A1 <= A4) OR (A1 <= A2 AND A1 >= A3 AND A1 <= A4)) then     Q3 <=   A1; 
    elsif ((A2 <= A1 AND A2 <= A3 AND A2 >= A4 ) OR (A2 >= A1 AND A2 <= A3 AND A2 <= A4) OR (A2 <= A1 AND A2 >= A3 AND A2 <= A4)) then  Q3 <=   A2; 
    elsif ((A3 <= A1 AND A3 <= A2 AND A3 >= A4 ) OR (A3 >= A1 AND A3 <= A2 AND A3 <= A4) OR (A3 <= A1 AND A3 >= A2 AND A3 <= A4)) then  Q3 <=   A3;
    elsif ((A4 <= A1 AND A4 <= A2 AND A4 >= A3 ) OR (A4 >= A1 AND A4 <= A2 AND A4 <= A3) OR (A4 <= A1 AND A4 >= A2 AND A4 <= A3)) then  Q3 <=   A4;
    end if; 

    if (A1 <= A2 AND A1 <= A3 AND A1 <= A4 )then        Q4 <=   A1;
    elsif ( A2 <= A3 AND A2 <= A4 AND A2 <= A1) then    Q4 <=   A2;
    elsif( A3 <= A4 AND A3 <= A2 AND A3 <= A1 )then     Q4 <=   A3;
    elsif( A4 <= A3 AND A4 <= A2 AND A4 <= A1 )then     Q4 <=   A4;
    end if;
end if;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

and this is another code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;



entity COMPARE_2 is
    PORT(
        clock   :in STD_LOGIC;
        En  :in STD_LOGIC:='0';
        A1  :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        A2  :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        A3  :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        A4  :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";

        Q1  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        Q2  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        Q3  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        Q4  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        done    :OUT    STD_LOGIC:='0'

    );
end COMPARE_2;

architecture Behavioral of COMPARE_2 is
    type Com2StateMachine is (C2_start,C2_sort1,C2_sort2,C2_sort3,C2_sort4,C2_done);
    signal Com2State : Com2StateMachine:=C2_start;
begin
    process(clock)
    begin
        if(clock'event and clock ='1') then
        c2case: case Com2State is
            when C2_start =>
                if( En='1') then    
                    Com2State <= C2_sort1;
                end if;
            when C2_sort1 =>
                    if (A1 >= A2 AND A1 >= A3 AND A1 >= A4) then    Q1 <=   A1; 
                    elsif (A2 >= A3 AND A2 >= A4 AND A2 >= A1) then Q1 <=   A2;
                    elsif( A3 >= A2 AND A3 >= A4 AND A3 >= A1) then Q1 <=   A3;
                    elsif( A4 >= A3 AND A4 >= A2 AND A4 >= A1) then Q1 <=   A4;
                    end if;
                    Com2State <= C2_sort2;
            when C2_sort2 =>
                    if ((A1 <= A2 AND A1 >= A3 AND A1 >= A4 ) OR (A1 >= A2 AND A1 <= A3 AND A1 >= A4) OR (A1 >= A2 AND A1 >= A3 AND A1 <= A4) ) then    Q2 <=   A1; 
                    elsif ((A2 <= A1 AND A2 >= A3 AND A2 >= A4 ) OR (A2 >= A1 AND A2 <= A3 AND A2 >= A4) OR (A2 >= A1 AND A2 >= A3 AND A2 <= A4)) then  Q2 <=   A2; 
                    elsif ((A3 <= A1 AND A3 >= A2 AND A3 >= A4 ) OR (A3 >= A1 AND A3 <= A2 AND A3 >= A4) OR (A3 >= A1 AND A3 >= A2 AND A3 <= A4)) then  Q2 <=   A3; 
                    elsif ((A4 <= A1 AND A4 >= A2 AND A4 >= A3 ) OR (A4 >= A1 AND A4 <= A2 AND A4 >= A3) OR (A4 >= A1 AND A4 >= A2 AND A4 <= A3)) then  Q2 <=   A4; 
                    end if;
                    Com2State <= C2_sort3;
            when C2_sort3 =>
                    if ((A1 <= A2 AND A1 <= A3 AND A1 >= A4 ) OR (A1 >= A2 AND A1 <= A3 AND A1 <= A4) OR (A1 <= A2 AND A1 >= A3 AND A1 <= A4)) then     Q3 <=   A1; 
                    elsif ((A2 <= A1 AND A2 <= A3 AND A2 >= A4 ) OR (A2 >= A1 AND A2 <= A3 AND A2 <= A4) OR (A2 <= A1 AND A2 >= A3 AND A2 <= A4)) then  Q3 <=   A2; 
                    elsif ((A3 <= A1 AND A3 <= A2 AND A3 >= A4 ) OR (A3 >= A1 AND A3 <= A2 AND A3 <= A4) OR (A3 <= A1 AND A3 >= A2 AND A3 <= A4)) then  Q3 <=   A3;
                    elsif ((A4 <= A1 AND A4 <= A2 AND A4 >= A3 ) OR (A4 >= A1 AND A4 <= A2 AND A4 <= A3) OR (A4 <= A1 AND A4 >= A2 AND A4 <= A3)) then  Q3 <=   A4;
                    end if; 
                    Com2State <= C2_sort4;
            when C2_sort4 =>
                    if (A1 <= A2 AND A1 <= A3 AND A1 <= A4 )then        Q4 <=   A1;
                    elsif ( A2 <= A3 AND A2 <= A4 AND A2 <= A1) then    Q4 <=   A2;
                    elsif( A3 <= A4 AND A3 <= A2 AND A3 <= A1 )then     Q4 <=   A3;
                    elsif( A4 <= A3 AND A4 <= A2 AND A4 <= A1 )then     Q4 <=   A4;
                    end if;
                    Com2State <= C2_done;
            when C2_done =>                     
                    done<='1';
                    if (En='0') then
                        Com2State <= C2_start;
                    end if;
            end case c2case;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

and this is another code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;



entity COMPARE_2 is
    PORT(
        clock   :in STD_LOGIC;
        En  :in STD_LOGIC:='0';
        A1  :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        A2  :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        A3  :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        A4  :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";

        Q1  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        Q2  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        Q3  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        Q4  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"FF";
        done    :OUT    STD_LOGIC:='0'

    );
end COMPARE_2;

architecture Behavioral of COMPARE_2 is
    type ArrVec4 is array (0 to 3) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    function sort(data :  ArrVec4) return ArrVec4 is
        variable tmp: ArrVec4;
        variable tmp2: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    begin
    l0: for k in 0 to 3 loop
            tmp(k):=data(k);
        end loop l0;
    l1: for i in 0 to 2 loop
    l2:     for j in i+1 to 3 loop
                if(tmp(i) >= tmp(j)) then
                    tmp2 := tmp(j);
                    tmp(j) := tmp(i);
                    tmp(i) := tmp2;
                end if;
            end loop l2;
        end loop l1;
        return tmp;
    end sort;
--SIGNALS:

    signal i: ArrVec4;
    signal oVec : ArrVec4;


    type Com2StateMachine is (C2_start,C2_sort1,C2_sort2,C2_sort3,C2_done);
    signal Com2State : Com2StateMachine:=C2_start;
begin
    process(clock)
    begin
        if(clock'event and clock ='1') then
        c2case: case Com2State is
            when C2_start =>
                if( En='1') then    
                    Com2State <= C2_sort1;
                end if;
            when C2_sort1 =>
                    i(0) <= A1;
                    i(1) <= A2;
                    i(2) <= A3;
                    i(3) <= A4;
                    Com2State <= C2_sort2;
            when C2_sort2 =>
                    oVec <= sort(i);
                    Com2State <= C2_sort3;
            when C2_sort3 =>
                    Q4 <= oVec(3);
                    Q3 <= oVec(2);
                    Q2 <= oVec(1);
                    Q1 <= oVec(0);
                    Com2State <= C2_done;
            when C2_done =>                     
                    done<='1';
                    if (En='0') then
                        Com2State <= C2_start;
                    end if;
            end case c2case;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

all of these three codes is sequential code but we know compare and sort doesn't need "clock" , I wrote another code with "WHEN" in concurrence... and all of this code work in simulation right and my clock speed in Xillinx Spartan3 is 30 MHz and ISE say that I can have 59 Mhz Clock speed for this code. it works even when I wrote a test component with using UART, but when I use this codes in my simple component about Median Filter and in large number of calculation. it doesn't work but when I use a sort code that do Sorting in 8 clock, I give answer.
I need to mention that I instance this component in this code for use 2 , 4 byte sort for calculating median of 8 element:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity COMPARE_8 is
    PORT(
        clock   :IN std_logic:='0';
        en  :IN std_logic:='0';
        A1  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        A2  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        A3  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        A4  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        A5  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        A6  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        A7  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        A8  :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);

        Q4  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        Q5  :OUT    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
        done    :OUT    std_logic:='0'
    );
end COMPARE_8;

architecture Behavioral of COMPARE_8 is
    COMPONENT COMPARE_2
    PORT(
        clock : IN std_logic;
        En : IN std_logic:='0';
        A1 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        A2 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        A3 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        A4 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);          
        Q1 : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Q2 : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Q3 : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Q4 : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        done :OUT   STD_LOGIC:='0'
        );
    END COMPONENT;
    for All: COMPARE_2 use entity WORK.COMPARE_2(Behavioral);

    type ComStateMachine is (C_start,C_sort,C_wait,C_done);
    signal ComState : ComStateMachine:=C_start;
    --SIGNALS:
    SIGNAL i1:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"05";
    SIGNAL i2:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"05";
    SIGNAL i3:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"05";
    SIGNAL i4:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"05";
    SIGNAL i5:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"05";
    SIGNAL i6:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"05";
    SIGNAL i7:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"05";
    SIGNAL i8:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"05";

    SIGNAL O1:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"07";
    SIGNAL O2:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"07";
    SIGNAL O3:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"06";
    SIGNAL O4:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"06";
    SIGNAL O5:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"06";
    SIGNAL O6:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"06";
    SIGNAL O7:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"06";
    SIGNAL O8:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0):=x"06";

    signal enSort:STD_LOGIC:='0';
    signal doSort1:STD_LOGIC:='0';
    signal doSort2:STD_LOGIC:='0';
    signal clk:STD_LOGIC:='0';

begin
    Inst1_COMPARE_2: COMPARE_2 PORT MAP(
        clock => clk,
        En => enSort,
        A1 => i1,
        A2 => i2,
        A3 => i3,
        A4 => i4,
        Q1 => O1,
        Q2 => O2,
        Q3 => O3,
        Q4 => O4,
        done => doSort1
    );
    Inst2_COMPARE_2: COMPARE_2 PORT MAP(
        clock => clk,
        En => enSort,
        A1 => i5,
        A2 => i6,
        A3 => i7,
        A4 => i8,
        Q1 => O5,
        Q2 => O6,
        Q3 => O7,
        Q4 => O8,
        done => doSort2
    );

    clk<= clock;
    process(clock)
    begin
        if( clock'event and clock='1' ) then
        c0Case: case ComState is
            when C_start =>
                done<='0';
                if(En = '1') then
                    i1<=A1;
                    i2<=A2;
                    i3<=A3;
                    i4<=A4;
                    i5<=A5;
                    i6<=A6;
                    i7<=A7;
                    i8<=A8;
--                  i1<=x"09";
--                  i2<=x"02";
--                  i3<=x"03";
--                  i4<=x"06";
--                  i5<=x"2b";
--                  i6<=x"1a";
--                  i7<=x"0c";
--                  i8<=x"01";
                    ComState <= C_sort;
                end if;
            when C_sort =>
                enSort<='1';
                ComState <= C_wait;
            when C_wait =>
                if(doSort1='1' and doSort2='1') then
                    enSort<='0';
                    if( O5 <= O4 ) then
                        Q4 <= O4;
                        Q5 <= O5;
                    end if;
                    if( O6 <= O3 AND O6 >= O4 ) then 
                        Q5 <= O6;
                    end if;
                    if( O7 <= O2 AND O7 >= O3) then
                        Q5 <= O7;
                    end if;
                    if( O8 <= O1 AND O8 >= O2)then 
                        Q5 <=O8;
                    end if;

                    if(O1 <= O8 )then
                        Q5 <= O1;
                    end if;
                    if( O2 <= O7 AND O2 >= O8)then
                        Q5 <=O2;
                    end if;
                    if( O3 <= O6 AND O3 >= O7)then
                        Q5 <=O3;
                    end if;
                    if(O4 <= O5 AND O4 >= O6)then
                        Q5 <=O4 ;
                    end if;

                    if( O5 <= O3 AND O5 >= O4) then
                        Q4 <= O5;
                    end if;
                    if( O6 <= O2 AND O6 >= O3)then
                        Q4 <= O6;
                    end if;
                    if(O7 <= O1 AND O7 >= O2 )then
                        Q4 <= O7;
                    end if;
                    if( O8 >= O1) then
                        Q4 <= O8;
                    end if;
                    if( O1 <= O7 AND O1 >= O8 )then
                        Q4 <= O1;
                    end if;
                    if( O2 <= O6 AND O2 >= O7) then
                        Q4 <= O2;
                    end if;
                    if(O3 <= O5 AND O3 >= O6)then
                        Q4 <= O3;
                    end if;
--                  if(O3 <= O7 AND O3 >= O8)then
--                      Q4 <= O4;
--                  end if;
                    ComState <= C_done;
                end if;
            when C_done =>
                done<='1';
                if(En='0')then
                    ComState <= C_start;
                end if;
            end case c0Case;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

now I don't know why I can't use concurrence sorting with "when" and all of this codes run fine in simulation and can run maximum 59 Mhz and I have 30 Mhz clock?

"I gave that random default values for debugging my code"

Comment: You've dumped a lot of code on us with no specific question, no clear statement of what doesn't work or evidence of how it fails. I'm not going to try to guess what you want from this question.

Comment: the result of sort is incorrect Sir, when you calculate and use this sort in a picture's pixels.

Comment: If you don't want to answer me , why u say my question is not useful ?

Comment: Well for a start you still haven't said which of these sorts have incorrect results. All of them? Just the one you haven't shown us? Then you haven't given us any details of the "incorrect" results. The outputs might be identical to the inputs. Or all XXXX. Or treating signed numbers as unsigned. I don't know. And given your petulant attitude when I don't respond fast enough, I no longer care.

Comment: no. in simulation it works fine, and when I run on fpga for 3 or 4 times. but some times it gives me insecure answers just some times however a sequential sort(uses 9 clock) that I use always is right!

Comment: This line ` clk<= clock;` may cause problems. Assign `clock` to every sub-component directly.

Comment: sorry sir how I should Assign clock to every sub-component directly?

Comment: Just write `clock => clock` in the instantiation of Compare_2.

Comment: no I wrote that for test another solution to solve this problem.

Comment: The line `clk <= clock` incurs an extra delta cycle delay in simulation. Thus, the flip-flops in the sub-components will not toggle at the same time as in the main component anymore. If you need this make it work in simulation, then it will not work on the FPGA. The FPGA always behaves as with the direct assignment `clock => clock` in the instantiation.

Comment: Did you specified timing constraints in a UCF file or did you just took a look at the synthesis report for the minimum path delay? Please note, that the latter is only an approximation.

Comment: After re-reading the question, I'm still confused. Does the alternate sorting in 8 clock cycles (which works) also use the `COMPARE_2` entity?

Comment: none of them. tnx I got my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside of great equal

> (>=)

or less equal

> (<=)

---

just change the operators' conditions to **>** or **<** 
and just use **>=** or **<=** once for each statement.

Answer (score -1):

To sort 4 elements in hardware, you might consider using a sorting network, wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network

In this case, 5 if / swap sequence:

```
    if (a[0] > a[2]) { swap(a[0], a[2]); }
    if (a[1] > a[3]) { swap(a[1], a[3]); }
    if (a[0] > a[1]) { swap(a[0], a[1]); }
    if (a[2] > a[3]) { swap(a[2], a[3]); }
    if (a[1] > a[2]) { swap(a[1], a[2]); }
```

Comment: "if" and "swaping" need Clock, right? 
but "sort" or "compare" don't need clock.
when I can write a "Cencurrent code" why i should write a "Sequential code"?!

Comment: @Prof.Hell - {a[0], a[2} and {a[1], a[3]} operations can be done in parallel on the first cycle. {a[0], a[1} and {a[2], a[3]} operations can be done in parallel on the second cycle. This leaves {a[1], a[2} for the third cycle. So time wise, it's 3 cycles. The wiki article explains this.

Comment: thanks for answer but:
Q1 <=A1 WHEN(A1 >= A2 AND A1 >= A3 AND A1 >= A4) ELSE
   A2 WHEN (A2 >= A3 AND A2 >= A4 AND A2 >= A1) ELSE
   A3 WHEN( A3 >= A2 AND A3 >= A4 AND A3 >= A1) ELSE
   A4;
this a part of Cencurrent code and can make with simple gates. when your input changes your out put changes after gate delays. no need cycle or clock

Comment: for Q2,Q3 and Q4 you can write something like this.(convert "if" to "when")

Comment: @Prof.Hell - It's a lot of compares, and four final assignments (Q1 to Q4), but they're all in parallel, so although it takes more gates, it's faster and you just need a propagation delay.

Comment: you say right but my question is this:
why these codes run indecisive (insecure)?
but when you simulate those or run 2 or 3 times in FPGA works good.
and the max delay they need is less than 20ns.

Comment: @Prof.Hell - doesn't VHDL include a worst case delay calculation to determine when the outputs would be stable?